# Issue while converting each page of pdf file to an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to convert any type of file (e.g. pdf, xlsx, docs, etc.) into an image using javascript. I converted all files to a base64, but in image src tag when I pass base64 value it is downloading the file in format such as like doc, ppt etc, But I need in image format in JPEG or png.

Comment: can you add sample code here or reproduce this in https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: Please provider more information about your code, preferably in a repository such as https://stackblitz.com/.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask can help you frame your question so it is easier for people to help you.